# How to add certificate in android 6.0.1 programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, x509certificate

I have this certificate file as **'digithon.allianz.com_base64.cer'** on my local system. I want to add this file programmatically to my application. So far after a lot of R&D I have found this:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

I don't know exactly how to use this with the application that I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _add this file programmatically to my application_: to do what? What is the issue?

Comment: I want my application to accept the certificate 'digithon.allianz.com_base64.cer' so that the user could register and generate an OTP which he'll receive via his provided email. When I install my certificate using the device, like copying the certificate to the phone and then installing. This doesn't work either. Gives an error: "02-14 15:04:38.683 14771-14771/com.allianz.azemployee I/Aditi: errorMsg== java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://digithon.allianz.com/DigithonEmpWebService/rest/authService/empAppAuthentication}"

Comment: that site use a certificate issued by Verisign. The root certificate of this CA is installed in your device, so your issue is not related with SSL connection (you do not need to install the leaf certificate "digithon.allianz.com". Just the root)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? Need a bit more explanation on this --> "you do not need to install the leaf certificate "digithon.allianz.com". Just the root". Thank you!

Comment: Certificates are issued in a hierarchy, each certificate is signed by its issuer, from leaf certificate to root. This is the certification chain. The client has a trust store with the root certificate of accepted issuers. When a SSL connection is performed, the client will verify the certification chain of the server certificate, checking if there is a matching issuer certificate in the trust store. Verisign is a known CA and its root certificate is present in mostly client, so by default you do not need to add the digithon "certificate"